# Pass row numbers while using apply() function in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, data-cleaning

So basically what I am trying to do is to format date column. Dates are given as : 24th Mar, 5th Jul and so on. I wrote a function to split these and make it like 24/03 and 05/07. But the problem is that for rows 0 to 8 in my pandas data frame it is for 2021 and rest of the rows is for 2020. So basically with the current code I can make 24th Mar to 24/03 but I want it to be 24/03/2021 if row number is between 0 to 8 and 24/03/2021 if row number is after 8.

```
import operator

def dateConversion(date):
  day =''
  month = ''
  val_month = 0
  if operator.contains(date, "th"): 
    day, month = date.split("th")
  if operator.contains(date, "rd"): 
    day, month = date.split("rd")
  if operator.contains(date, "nd"):
    day, month = date.split("nd")
  if operator.contains(date, "st"):
    day, month = date.split("st")
  
  day = day.strip()

  if(int(day) < 10):
    day = str(day)
    day = '0' + day

  month = month.strip()
  months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] #list items based on data
  if month in months:
    val_month = months.index(month) + 1 #getting month value
  if(val_month < 10):
    val_month = str(val_month)
    val_month = '0' + val_month
  day = day + '/' + str(val_month) #+ '/' + year
  return day
```

And I have used below code to apply to column :

```
df_ipo['Listed Date_'] = df_ipo['Listed Date'].apply(lambda x: dateConversion(x))
```

How can I pass the row number as well with this apply function in dateConversion so that I can set year accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of row-wise parsing the dates (which can be slow) we can `replace` the abbreviations, and add the years to the first few rows. This then allows us to easily convert to a `datetime` dtype which has the ability easily format the dates into your strings with `strftime`.

I left all 4 columns (the original, with the abbreviations stripped and years added, the `datetime` and the string formatted date) for clarity, but there's no real reason to create all of these separate columns.

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['24th Mar', '5th Jul', '1st May', '2nd Jun', '3rd Jul',
                            '30th May', '21st Oct', '18th Dec', '5th Sep', '16th Dec']})
```

---

```
repl = {'1st': '1', '2nd': '2', '3rd': '3', '4th': '4', '5th': '5', 
        '6th': '6', '7th': '7', '8th': '8', '9th': '9', '0th': '0'}

df['date_strip'] = df['date'].replace(repl, regex=True)

# Add 2021 to first 8 rows, then 2020 to the rest
df['date_strip'] = df['date_strip'] + ' ' + (['2021']*8 + ['2020']*(len(df)-8))

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_strip, format='%d %b %Y')
df['date_fmt'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

---

```
       date   date_strip   datetime  date_fmt
0  24th Mar  24 Mar 2021 2021-03-24  24/03/21
1   5th Jul   5 Jul 2021 2021-07-05  05/07/21
2   1st May   1 May 2021 2021-05-01  01/05/21
3   2nd Jun   2 Jun 2021 2021-06-02  02/06/21
4   3rd Jul   3 Jul 2021 2021-07-03  03/07/21
5  30th May  30 May 2021 2021-05-30  30/05/21
6  21st Oct  21 Oct 2021 2021-10-21  21/10/21
7  18th Dec  18 Dec 2021 2021-12-18  18/12/21
8   5th Sep   5 Sep 2020 2020-09-05  05/09/20
9  16th Dec  16 Dec 2020 2020-12-16  16/12/20
```

Comment: This was very helpful and quite straight forward too. Thanks a lot.